# Write a generic method to replace a family of legacy API methods

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing code using a legacy API whose code I cannot change. There is a family of methods for supported datatypes (int, double, bool, string, APIObject) to do an operation in the API. These take a parameter of the same datatype as indicated in the name of the method. Sample usages as given below

```
GetIntExp(5)
GetStringExp("Hello")
GetDoubleExp(1.2)
GetDateExp(DateTime.Now)
GetAPIObjectExp(myObject)
```

The return type respectively, IntExp, StringExp, DoubleExp, DateExp and ObjectExp. All return types  inherit from a class (which interestingly is a generic type) `StaticOperator<T>` where T is the datatype.

Is it possible to write a generic method in my codebase which redirects calls to the suitable API method based on the datatype which is passed in?

Comment: You've shown four... but listed five. Can it really work with *any* object? Does it do the same thing for each operation? What's the return type?

Comment: I'm sorry for interrupting but there were three questions and only one answer :) Should it be considered "Yes, yes, yes"?

Comment: The problem of exposing a generic method is that, it would allow you to pass any data type. Even custom classes. What should the code do in those cases?

Comment: The called methods just create an expression which is executed on the server. The supported types are only the listed 5, object is a bit misleading as it refers to an instance of APIObject and not any object. The method will not be called with any other type, it can throw an exception if that happens.

Comment: I would use the command pattern. It will solve your problem and probably even help you in the future with extensions and so on.

Comment: I can't see the added value of using generic method that will redirect to the correct non generic method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to me you don't need a generic method at all, just a wrapper method for each supported argument type:

```
public IntExp GetExpression(int value)
{
    return GetIntExp(value);
}

public StringExp GetExpression(string value)
{
    return GetStringExp(value);
}
```

and so on (assuming your goal is to use the same name for all the ways of getting an expression).

Comment: It's a bit inelegant and a small DRY violation, but in this situation I think it's the best solution. Well, that or just calling the API methods directly, but I assume the OP has a reason for wanting to add an extra layer of abstraction

Comment: While this will work in many situations, in my case this method will be used in a generic method which forms a graph query to be executed on the server. There are other generic method calls it makes.

Comment: Actually I think this is a very good solution, because type overloading will figure it out at compile time. You can even add a `GetExpression((dynamic)myObject);` call if you have an object and want to use the right overload. And you can add the generic overload, which will be the fallback if the other things fail. +1 from me.

Comment: @RahulMisra Well consider Prescott's answer then, with minor tweaks so that it compiles

Comment: @RahulMisra I don't see the problem with making a graph query; the JustSearch API actually works like this under the hood.

Comment: @RahulMisra Could you show the context from which it will be called? That would appear to be some important but missing information!

Comment: I take my earlier comment back, this solution works for my case. The only change I had to make was casting the parameter which is a generic type in the calling method to dynamic. @Stefan suggested this in his comment.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _funcMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> {
    {typeof(Int), (input) => GetIntExp((int)input)},
    {typeof(string), (input) => GetStringExp((string)input)},
    ...
};

public StaticOperator<TType> GetExp<TType>(TType target) {
    Func<object, object> func;
    if (!_funcMapping.TryGetValue(typeof(TType), out func))
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    return (StaticOperator<TType>)func(target);
}
```

is totally possible, but certainly have scaling problems and quite unsafe as requires a lot of casting.

Of course you can rewrite it using `if .. elseif .. elseif .. elseif .. else`, but all in all it's just a checking if we have a suitable method.

Comment: Thanks J0hn, let me try this.

Comment: @J0hn `Func<object, object>` would cause boxing and unboxing of each method execution, wouldn't it?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes it would, but that might or might not be a show-stopper, as nothing expressed in question about this. I believe it's possible to avoid boxing-unboxing, but I'm not smart enough to program it in some sensible time :)

Comment: @J0HN, I used a combination of your first solution and Prescott's to get a working version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
public T GetExp<T>(T obj)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (type == typeof(int))
        return GetIntExp(obj);
    if (type == typeof(string))
        return GetStringExp(obj);
    if (type == typeof(double))
        return GetDoubleExp(obj);
    if (type == typeof(DateTime))
        return GetDateExp(obj);
    if (type == typeof(APIObject))
        return GetAPIObjectExp(obj);

    throw new Exception("Invalid Type");
}
```

Comment: `GetIntExp`, `GetStringExp`, ... return `StaticOperator<T>`, not just `T`

Comment: I don't think this will compile. The compiler can't confirm that the `GetFooExp` methods are returning the correct type. Casting might fix it.

Comment: I edited this slightly to get it compiling, but this works in principle.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got compiling and working using suggestions from @J0HN and @Prescott,

```
private StaticOperator<T> GetValue<T>(T comparandValue)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (type == typeof(int))
    {
        return GetIntVal((dynamic)comparandValue);
    }

    if (type == typeof(double))
    {
        return GetDoubleVal((dynamic)comparandValue);
    }

    if (type == typeof(string))
    {
        return GetStringVal((dynamic)comparandValue);
    }

    if (type == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        return GetDateVal((dynamic)comparandValue);
    }

    if (type == typeof(APIbject))
    {
        return GetObjectVal(comparandValue as APIObject);
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException("The given type is not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to write a generic method in my codebase which redirects calls to the suitable API method based on the datatype which is passed in."

You could write some IL-Code to do exactely that. Then again you'd probably not have a great time doing that. I've read an article on codeplex at home about it. I think i found it by googling "Replace method at runtime".

Maybe that's what you're looking for after all, though it might very well be the most difficult solution for your actual problem.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

Comment: Oh sorry, downvote was from me. This answer just seemed so clearly not the correct option for the OP's situation that I didn't see the point to it.

Comment: @BenAaronson In that case i just move past an answer instead of downvoting it, if it is an answer which would also provide a possible solution, no matter how complicated it is. As i pointed out in the answer, it would be the most difficult solution. Those hints are useful to get some more ideas when you've got a similar problem and are running out of ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: Right, but it's just so far removed from the question that it seems to me likely to do more harm than good. There's a reasonable scope for "in a slightly more general situation than the OP's" type answers, but this seems way beyond that. It's also not really an answer because the only content that is in the answer itself rather than on another site is "write some IL-Code". So, sorry if you don't agree with my reasoning. It is just a downvote so we may have to agree to disagree on whether it should be there.